# jQuery UI in Backbone View adds elements, but doesn't respond to events

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, backbone.js

I'm building an app in which I'm using Django on the backend and jQuery UI/Backbone to build the front. I'm pulling a Django-generated form into a page with jQuery.get() inside of a Backbone View. That part works fine, but now I want to add some jQuery UI stuff to the form (e.g. a datepicker, some buttons that open dialogs, etc). So, here's the relevant code:

```
var InstructionForm = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    var that = this;
    $.get(
      '/tlstats/instruction/new/',
      function(data) {
        var elements = $(data);
        $('#id_date', elements).datepicker();
        that.$el.html(elements.html());
      }
    };
    return this;
  }
});
```

The path /tlstats/instruction/new/ returns an HTML fragment with the form Django has generated. What's happening is that input#id_date is getting the hasDatePicker class added and the datepicker div is appended to my <body> element (both as expected), but when I click on input#id_date, nothing happens. No datepicker widget appears, no errors in the console. Why might this be happening?

Also, somewhat off-topic, but in trying to figure this problem out on my own, I've come across several code examples where people are doing stuff like:

```
$(function() {
  $('#dialog').dialog(...);
  ...
});
```

Then later:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize(): function() {
    this.el = $('#dialog');
  }
});
```

Isn't this defeating the purpose of Backbone, having all that jQuery UI code completely outside any Backbone structure? Or do I misunderstand the role of Backbone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is right here:

```
$('#id_date', elements).datepicker();
that.$el.html(elements.html());
```

First you bind the datepicker with `.datepicker()` and then you throw it all away by converting your `elements` to an HTML string:

```
that.$el.html(elements.html());
```

and you put that string into `$el`. When you say `e.html()`, you're taking a wrapped DOM object with event bindings and everything else and turning into a simple piece of HTML in a string, that process throws away everything (such as event bindings) that isn't simple HTML.

Either give `.html()` the jQuery object itself:

```
$('#id_date', elements).datepicker();
that.$el.html(elements);
```

or bind the datepicker after adding the HTML:

```
that.$el.html(elements);
that.$('#id_date').datepicker();
```

Comment: Does anyone have an idea how to rerender the view, which already had bindings? Rerender is important when the model state changes.

Comment: @mojovski: Maybe you should ask a new question, that would let you provide more context than a comment on something a year old.